# Database schema advice for storing form fields and field values

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-schema

I've been tasked with creating an application that allows users the ability to enter data into a web form that will be saved and then eventually used to populate pdf form fields.

I'm having trouble trying to think of a good way to store the field values in a database as the forms will be dynamic (based on pdf fields).

In the app itself I will pass data around in a hash table (fieldname, fieldvalue) but I don't know the best way to convert the hash to db values.

I'm using MS SQL server 2000 and asp.net webforms. Has anyone worked on something similar?

Comment: Perhaps you can share some of the fields and relationships with us. Sometimes, and it really depends on the purpose, tables have to be normalized, and sometimes, we have to denormalize tables (like in some cases of warehousing!) :)

Comment: I'm still in the very early stages of design so nothing has been finalized by any means. Most likely, as gview suggested below, I'm going to have a Form table that stores columns such as form type, created_on, etc... The form table will have a one to many relationship with a FormField table storing field name, type, and value.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is a insurance back office type app.  Field values will hold info such as driver license numbers to address fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a document database here? This is just the sort of problem they solve alot better than traditional RDBMS solutions. Personally, I'm a big fan of [RavenDb](http://www.ravendb.net). Another pretty decent option is [CouchDb](http://couchdb.apache.org/). I'd avoid MongoDb as it really isn't a safe place for data in it's current implementation.

Even if you can't use a document database, you can make SQL pretend to be one by setting up your tables to have some metadata in traditional columns with a payload field that is serialized XML or json. This will let you search on metadata while staying out of EAV-land. EAV-land is a horrible place to be.

UPDATE

I'm not sure if a good guide exists, but the concept is pretty simple. The basic idea is to break out the parts you want to query on into "normal" columns in a table -- this lets you query in standard manners. When you find the record(s) you want, you can then grab the CLOB and deserialize it as appropriate. In your case you would have a table that looked something like:

```
SurveyAnswers
  Id INT IDENTITY
  FormId INT
  SubmittedBy VARCHAR(255)
  SubmittedAt DATETIME
  FormData TEXT
```

A few protips:
a) use a text based serialization routine. Gives you a fighting chance to fix data errors and really helps debugging.
b) For SQL 2000, you might want to consider breaking the CLOB (TEXT field holding your payload data) into a separate table. Its been a long time since I used SQL 2000, but my recollection is using TEXT columns did bad things to tables.

Comment: I really love this idea. I was hoping to store info in json or xml but I'm very limited on database storage. Basically stuck with ms sql server 2000. Could you provide me some direction on where I can find documentation on using metadata in columns?

Comment: Just expanded the answer a bit; I have used this very successfully on Sql 2000 based apps FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for what you're describing is called [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (EAV) and this model can be a royal pain to deal with. So you should limit as much as possible your usage of this.

For example are there fields that are almost always in the forms (First Name, Last Name, Email etc) then you should put them in a table as fields.

The reason for this is because if you don't somebody sooner or later is going to realize that they have these names and emails and ask you to build this query

```
     SELECT 
        Fname.value fname,
        LName.Value lname,
        email.Value email,
        ....
     FROM  
         form f
         INNER JOIN formFields fname
         ON f.FormId = ff.FormID
            and AttributeName = 'fname'      
         INNER JOIN formFields lname
         ON f.FormId = ff.FormID
            and AttributeName = 'lname'
         INNER JOIN formFields email
         ON f.FormId = ff.FormID
            and AttributeName = 'email'
         ....
```

when you could have written this

```
    SELECT 
        common.fname,
        common.lname,
        common.email,
        ....
     FROM  
         form f
         INNER JOIN common c
         on f.FormId = c.FormId
```

Also get off of SQL 2000 as soon as you can because you're going to really miss the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) clause

Its also probably not a bad idea to look at previous [SO EAV questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=EAV) to give you an idea of problems that people have encountered in the past

Comment: Thanks for the input I'll definitely research EAV. I wish I could get off SQL 2000 but the powers that be will keep me there for a very long time I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest mirroring the same structure:

```
Form
-----
form_id
User
created

FormField
-------
formField_id
form_id
name
value
```